# Changing brightness Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, backlight

I try to change the screen brightness on Linux Mint! The keys are showing a change, but the screen keeps at full denisity. Changing the /sys/class/backlight/apple_backlight/backlight file has also no effect. Maybe an idea?

Comment: Yeah...you could tell us what hardware you have...

Comment: In addition to the hardware, please mention _which_ Mint you are using and which desktop environment.

Comment: heres my hardware: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.0-aluminum-13-late-2008-unibody-specs.html

Comment: I`m running Linux Mint 15/Cinnamon